# ubuntu installation audio crackling hissing, related to mouse, keyboard and GUI

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I have an audio issue after newly installing Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic.

I've plugged my audio into my hifi through the line-out on the back of the machine and there is a random but continual hissing, crackling or popping noise coming through.

There are so many people asking about sound issues on askubuntu that I was convinced I'd find the answer, but no. I'll list the symtoms and what I've tried.

The noise is mostly generated by the system - by mouse movement or key presses, and is better or worse depending on what is on the screen. This askubuntu page for example makes it quite bad.

- the volume of the interference doesn't change with the volume settings
- the noise never goes away, regardless of whether I'm playing music or leaving the pc idle
- I can drown it out by turning the volume up with loud music
- sounds play fine with no other issues except this interference
- even when the PC is not on, the power supply makes some sort of interference - not loud, but distinct - which stops as soon as I pull the power cable out
- I have muted the mic input
- I've played with different volumes and enabled settings in alsamixer
- I've tried disabling sound power auto-save, following answers here showing how to use cmds like `echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save`
- I've gone into `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to add parameters to the `load module-udev-detect`

The PC has an Intel 200 Series PCH HD Audio and the chip is Realtek ALC1220

It's meant to be quite good:

> Audio Noise Guard
>
> GIGABYTE Z370 motherboards feature an audio noise guard that
>   essentially separates the board’s sensitive analog audio components
>   from potential noise pollution at the PCB level. LED trace path
>   lighting Illuminates to show the separation of the PCB layers.

[Gigabyte](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z370N-WIFI-rev-10#kf)

**UPDATE 1**

I added an item to the list above about the power supply also adding to the interference.

**UPDATE 2**

I shifted the power lead from the wall socket to the protected socket block that has surge protection on it, even though they're on the same circuit in my appartment. That improved things a little.

Then I borrowed a Meridian Explorer DAC from a friend. It was found out-of-the-box by Ubuntu and loaded up its drivers. I played movie sound through it in VLC. It only improved things a little. It cut out some of the hum but the clicks and whirrs from mouse or keyboard action were just as bad.

The big question is now, shall I bother trying a Windows installation on the machine to see if Windows can handle it? Or shall I just send the mobo back to the supplier?

Comment: Mouse movements wake up the CPU to redraw the cursor, which increases power usage by a little bit; this sounds as if your line-out circuit has lousy power supply rejection.

Comment: What is power supply rejection? See my edit about the motherboard audio which I took from the gigabyte website.

Comment: [PSRR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_rejection_ratio). Whom do you believe, that website or your lying ears?

Comment: As a workaround, you could try to run all CPU cores at 100% all the time, e.g., by searching [for aliens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SETI@home) or [prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Internet_Mersenne_Prime_Search), or by mining bitcoins.

Comment: ROFL! But seriously, how often would the CPU sleep? The noises created are diverse, not just a click or a crackle. There are hums, whistles, taps, depending on what I do. For instance, moving the mouse smoothly across the screen produces a steady zipping noise.  In fact, even after turning the machine off, there is still a quiet noise coming out, presumably from the capacitors all winding down.

Comment: Pretty much everything your computer does requires the CPU to wake up; this includes timer interrupts. So the effect is worse when it's mostly idle and sleeps most of the time.

Comment: OK, I hear you. I'm surprised because my old PC has nothing like this level of background noise. Am I correct that this is a sound card problem? I have plans to invest in an external USB DAC anyway, which would obsolete the sound card and solve the problem, am I correct?

Comment: If the USB DAC does not filter the USB power supply, it will have the same problem.

Comment: @CL I tried a USB DAC. Problem not solved. See my update. Just to be clear, should I blame the DAC, the mobo sound card, the mobo itself, or Ubuntu?

Comment: This is a hardware problem; you have to use a different mobo (or a USB DAC with its own filtered power supply). Both the CPU power supply and the HDA output are part of the same mobo, so this is entirely Gigabyte's fault (and their claim is a lie). At least they did not make any claims about the USB power …

Comment: @CL. if I plug my headphones into the line-out, I don't get the noise. What's going on there? My headphones are quite simple. Why does the interference come through to the hifi? Is there some kind of feedback going on?

Comment: Probably a ground loop; the headphones are floating and wouldn't notice a change in the line output's ground potential.